# How to submit 2 or more values with one button in JSP Form

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets

I have a table in which there are several rows. For instance a table with flight reservations. To delete one reservation I need to have the customer id number as well as the flight id.

Considering I have only one button to try to submit these values to my Servlet, how do I do so?

I tried hiding one button but the solution doesn't seem to work for me.
I use `request.getParameter()` (with 2 separate variables of course) to try to fetch both values but at the end only one is captured and the other is null. Any other ideas?

This is an example of the table I have.

```
flight_id    customer_id   
Value 1       Value 2
```

Form buttons :

```
<section class="about-info-area section-gap">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <form method="post" action="/admin_reservations" id="form_reservation"></form>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="float: left;">
            <caption style="text-align: center; caption-side: top"><h2>Liste des réservations</h2></caption>
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">N°Flight</th>
                <th scope="col">N°Client</th>
                <th scope="col">Flight price</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <% for (Reservation reservation : allReservations) { %>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><% out.println(reservation.getFlight().getFlightNum()); %></th>
                <td><% out.println(reservation.getClientNum()); %></td>
                <td><% out.println(reservation.getFlightPrice()); %> €</td>

                <td align="center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" name="delete_reservation_client"
                            form="form_reservation" onClick="window.location.reload();" hidden
                            value="<% out.println(reservation.getClientNum()); %>">
                    </input>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" name="delete_reservation_flight"
                            form="form_reservation" onClick="window.location.reload();"
                            value="<% out.println(reservation.getFlight().getFlightNum()); %>"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%}%>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my Servlet :

```
if(request.getParameter("delete_reservation_client")!=null &&request.getParameter("delete_reservation_flight")!=null){
        int delete_reservation_client = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("delete_reservation_client").trim());
        int delete_reservation_flight = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("delete_reservation_flight").trim());
        System.out.println("Client : " + delete_reservation_client);
        System.out.println("Flight : " + delete_reservation_flight);

        try {
            DBUtils.deleteReservation(conn,delete_reservation_client,delete_reservation_flight);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Fares

Comment: Try to post relevent code as well .

Comment: @Swati sorry, it's done now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `button` use `<a>` tag and attached both value which you want to delete . i.e :

```
<td align="center">
    <a href="/admin_reservations?delete_reservation_client=<% out.println(reservation.getClientNum()); %>&delete_reservation_flight=<% out.println(reservation.getFlight().getFlightNum()); %>">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
     Delete
 </a>
```

And in `Servlet` get these values in `doGet` method by writing i.e `request.getParameter("delete_reservation_client")` and `request.getParameter("delete_reservation_flight")`

Comment: May I ask why you put "?" before "delete_reservation_client" and "&" before delete_reservation_flight?

Comment: `?` ->  it identifes  beginning of the query string and `&` is used to append variable  i.e you in your case there are 2 value that needed to be pass .i.e : `http://example.org?variable1=value1&variable2=value2`